# How do I make the background of a SwiftUI list transparent?

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, styling

I am trying to make the list transparent so just the number of steps and the date they were taken appear on the background. Is there a way to make the grey background transparent and also do the same to the white in the cells of the list?

```
CustomNavigationLink(title: "Steps (Last 7 Days)") {
    List(listSteps, id: \.id) { stepList in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(stepList.count)")
                .font(.custom(customFont, size: 40))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            Text(stepList.date, style: .date)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .font(.custom(customFont, size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                .padding(1)
        }
    }
    .background(Image("GreenBG"))
    .navigationTitle("Steps (last 7 days)")
    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to set your VStack's list row background to clear:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("\(stepList.count)")
        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 40))
        .fontWeight(.semibold)            
    Text(stepList.date, style: .date)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 20))
        .foregroundColor(.cyan)
        .padding(1)
}
.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Now the grey background has disappeared. Do you know if there is a way to get rid of all the white in the list? So that it just displays the number of steps and the date they were taken?

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac.